# Display CR and LF rather than "EOL" in ':set list'

Tags: vimrc

Rather than choosing one character to be displayed as the EOL character, I'd like one to display for both CR and LF separately and regardless of if the file is unix or dos. Is this possible?

Comment: So if I understand you correctly you want something like `Hello%$` for DOS files (where `%` is a CR and `$` is a `LF`)? This isn't possible with the `list`/`listchars` setting, and I can't really come up with a way to do this in VimScript either...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker That's correct. Apart from `set list` is there a way to have `CR` and `LF` show as specific characters maybe?

Comment: You might be able to highlight them a certain color, but there isn't any way of showing them as specific characters that isn't hacky afaik.

Comment: I think either CR or LF can be seen at a time, not both.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that can't be done. Don't forget you can add an indicator to your statusline though. E.g. `:set stl+=\ [%{&ff}]`

Comment: This is not possible

Comment: @Antony is there a way to make it display `[LF]` and `[CRLF]` instead of `[unix]` and `[dos]`?

Comment: `set stl+=\ [%{&ff=='mac'?'CR':&ff=='unix'?'LF':'CRLF'}]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some caveats, you can do this using Vim's binary mode. It seems you might want to use the command

```
vim -b +'set list' somefile
```

Alternatively, you can put the following in your `.vimrc`:

```
:set binary
:set list
```

The important thing is that binary mode must get set *before* the file in question is read into a buffer. Once Vim has read the file in, it's too late; this trick relies on changing how Vim reads the file in. Specifically, what you need is for Vim to *not* attempt to guess the file's particular type of `<EOL>`.

Binary mode does what you want, disabling this automatic line-separator detection, but it does quite a few other things as well:

- sets `'textwidth'` to 0
- sets `'wrapmargin'` to 0
- unsets `'modeline'`
- unsets `'expandtab'`

So you might not want to have this in your `.vimrc`; it might be better to use the command-line version, and only for those files where you need this special kind of display.

For more information:

- `:help 'binary'`
- `:help edit-binary`
- `:help file-read`
- `:help file-formats`
- `:help 'fileformat'`

Comment: `but it does quite a few other things as well` is this because binary is a `FileType` with some auto commands or is it some sort of built in, unavoidable thing?

Comment: By that phrase, I meant to introduce the list that immediately follows it.

Comment: Right, I just didn't quote the whole thing :) What I meant was does it do those things because it uses some `FileType` called `binary` with those auto commands or was it just some built in thing?

Comment: Ah, right. None of this has anything to do with file types (but it is quite caught up in file formats). this is part of binary mode itself. See `:help 'binary'`. And maybe `:help 'fileformat'`.

Answer (score 1):

If you add to your `~/.vimrc`:

```
set ffs=unix
set list
```

That will always show `CR` as `^M` and `LF` as `$`.

By default, vim would interpret a file that only has `CRLF` endings as a dos file and show `CRLF` as `$`. By setting `ffs=unix`, you force vim to always open as a unix file, and therefore the CR is treated as an extra character.

Note: Be careful if modifying and saving dos files though. If you press `ENTER`, it will only insert a `LF`. You would need to manually insert a `CR` by typing `CTRL+V, CTRL+M`.